# What means: "Your XML configuration validates against a deprecated schema. Migrate your XML configuration using "--migrate-configuration"!"

Tags: php, phpunit

I have included PHPUnit in a test vanilla PHP project and when I start the test with `vendor/bin/phpunit` I get the following error message:

`Your XML configuration validates against a deprecated schema. Migrate your XML configuration using "--migrate-configuration"!`

**Question:** What does this error message mean and what do I have to do to avoid it?

**My phpunit.xml file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**I using phpunit 10**

```json
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 56):

Run `vendor/bin/phpunit --migrate-configuration`

Comment: if the XML file is somewhere else: `vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml --migrate-configuration`

Answer (score 3):

If you have upgraded to Laravel10, according to [Laravel website](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies), you should do this:

if you wish to use `PHPUnit 10`, you should delete the `processUncoveredFiles` attribute from the `<coverage>` section of your application's phpunit.xml configuration file. Then, update the following dependencies in your application's `composer.json` file:

```
nunomaduro/collision to ^7.0

phpunit/phpunit to ^10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try once below, [read more here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/810)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="true"
>
    <include>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </include>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I get new Error: `<include>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </include>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but my < include > tag was inside a < coverage > tag.

Before

```
<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </include>
</coverage>
```

After

```
<source>
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </include>
</source>
```